# VB.NET Upload to FTP failing when file name is changable

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I am trying to write upload a TXT file to an FTP site. the code works fine with a pre-defined name, however ideally the txt file name will be date and time stamped. so the code I'm using fails with an error "argumentexception was unhandled - Illegal charters in path - probably as I am trying to use a wildcard for the file name.....any thoughts - code as below.

HOW THE FILE IS CREATED

```
Dim filewriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\file_folder\filename" & "_" & Format(Today(), "yyyymmdd") & "_" & Format(Today(), "hhmmss") & "_ord.txt")

FTP UPLOAD SECTION - WORKS IS FILE NAME IS EXACT.

'Open an FTP connection and upload new order file

Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = directCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.FTPADDRESS.com/ed2*"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("USER", "PASS")
request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

**********ERROR HAPPENS HERE****************

Dim file() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\file_folder\filename*")
*******************************************

Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
strz.Close()
strz.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the guidance, I sorted this out a couple of months back but thought its worth posting the fix.

```
 Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftpaddress" & "_" & Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") & "_ORD.txt"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
            request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass")
                request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
                Dim file() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(order_file)
                Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
                strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
                strz.Close()
                strz.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

That method won't accept Wildcards and requires the full path of the file you're converting to a Byte array, the character you're trying to use is invalid.

Are you able to store the full file path in a variable then pass the variable into System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()?

Comment: that was my most recent train of thought.....still trying to work out how though.
thinking of "Public FILENAME as File" haven't worked out how to assign the file created to the variable though.

Comment: If you would like help in deciding the best way to structure your method, please may you explain the context in which you're needing to create and upload the file and I will be happy to help the best I can.